# Chinease and Japanese Typeface Example?

Tags: fonts, typeface

I am able to use diff EN fonts in my app but unable to use same for JP or CH fonts any solution .. ?

Problem is i tried 10-12 diff JP CH Fonts but not displaying tried ttf & ttc fonts whats might be problem .. ?

Is this is problem of keyboard-font mismatch ?

English Example http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-using-external-fonts/

```
tf3 = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "EN_3.TTF");
en3b.setTypeface(tf3);
```

// WORKS FINE

```
tf4 = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "CN_1.TTC");
cn1b.setTypeface(tf4);
```

// REMAINS BLANK // Tried many TTC & TTF fonts

```
tf7 = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "JP_1.TTC");
jp1b.setTypeface(tf7);
```

// REMAINS BLANK // Tried many TTC & TTF fonts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

// My each XML starts with this so am i on UTF-8 encoading ok .. ?

```
===== SOLUTION FOUND ======

UPGRADING EMULATOR FROM 2.2 to 2.3.3 SOLVED PROBLEM

MODS CAN CLOSE THIS Q
```

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 instead of your latin. Most established fonts (arial, our fav; times new roman) support the characters but you need to set you environment (or rendered files) to a utf-8 charset at the min

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

// My each XML starts with this so am i on UTF-8 encoading ok .. ?